# Why am I unable to print the x or y coordinate from my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coming across an error in my code that won't allow me to simply print the x or y inputted integers.

```
class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def getx(self):
        return self.x
```

When trying to call getx, however, I get the following response:

```
<bound method Coordinate.getx of <__main__.Coordinate object at 0x105a4ee10>>
```

I've tried calling it inside print(), I don't know why it's responding with that.

Comment: `mine.getx` or `mine.getx()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you aren't calling it, you are referencing it.  You need to print `instance.getx()`, not `instance.getx`.